# Finding the number of addtion steps for a recursive program

Tags: algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

I was going through a sample quiz and seem to have a hard time understanding 1 particular question.

5. The Fibonacci sequence 1,1,2,3, ... can be generated iteratively by starting with the first
   two (0th and 1st) and generating every subsequent one by adding the previous two. Thus, if
   we start with the first two, the nth Fibonacci number, for n ≥ 2, can be generated by n − 1
   additions. In particular, we need 6 additions to generate the 7th Fibonacci number. However,
   a recursive program to generate the 7th Fibonacci number needs:

(a) 20 additions
(c) 5 additions
(b) 13 additions
(d) 18 additions

Answer: a) 20 additions

I don't quite understand how they got 20 additions. Is there a quick way to find the additions for a recursive program for a fibonacci sequence? I tried tracing through a recursive code in c that I found online but I wasn't sure what I would consider to be addition steps.

I'm just looking for an explanation of how to arrive at the answer. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a little table with the number of additions needed for the n-th number. When you calculate the number f(x) as f(x-1) + f(x-2) you need the additions to calculate f(x-1) and the additions for f(x-2) and one more for the sum of the two numbers.

```
n     additions
0     0
1     0
2     1 (= n(0) + n(1) + 1)
3     2 (= n(1) + n(2) + 1)
4     4 (= n(2) + n(3) + 1)
5     7 (= n(3) + n(4) + 1)
6    12 (= n(4) + n(5) + 1)
7    20 (= n(5) + n(6) + 1)
```

Comment: Both answers were great, but I liked this explanation better since I was a bit confused on how to look at the Fibonacci sequence. I assumed the sequence was 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 where the first value in the sequence is 0. But it seems the Fibonacci sequence starts at 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 where index 0 has a value of 1 in the sequence? Either-way this was helpful since its a shorter method then writing out the whole output. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

A naive recursive formula will be something like:

```
F(0) = 1
F(1) = 1
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

so one way to look at it is to just do the substitutions...

```
F(7) = F(6) + F(5)
     = F(5) + F(4) + F(4) + F(3)
     = F(4) + F(3) + F(3) + F(2) + F(3) + F(2) + F(2) + F(1)
     = F(3) + F(2) + F(2) + F(1) + F(2) + F(1) + F(1) + F(0) + F(2) + F(1) + F(1) + F(0) + 1
     = F(2) + F(1) + F(1) + F(0) + F(1) + F(0) + 1 + F(1) + F(0) + 1 + 1 + 1 + F(1) + F(0) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
     = F(1) + F(0) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
     = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

...and add the + signs.

Alternately, note that each step of the recursive formula ends with F(1) and or F(0) and each of these has value 1. So for any n > 1, (after expanding the formula out) you will be summing enough 1's to make F(n). Therefore, the naive recursive formula will always need F(n)-1 additions (so in the case of F(7)=21, that is 20 additions).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the relationship with the number of additions and the Fibonacci sequence itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute this quickly with a closed formula requiring the current and previous Fibonacci numbers for all `n>0`.

```
S(n) = F(n-1) + F(n) -1
```

Where `Sn` is the number of additions for the nth term and `F(n)` and `F(n-1)` are the `nth` and the `nth-1` Fibonacci numbers.

For example:

```
S(10) = F(9) + F(10) -1

S(10) = 34 + 55 - 1

S(10) = 88
```